# Parsing inner JSON inside FluentD

Tags: logging, fluentd

I have some JSON being emitted from a docker container via the FluentD driver like:

```
'{"timeMillis":1485917543709,"thread":"main","level":"INFO","loggerName":"com.imageintelligence.ava.api.Boot","message":"{\"dom\":\"DOM\"}","loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger","threadId":1,"threadPriority":5}'
```

Notice the `message` field is string encoded JSON? When this data is captured by fluentD, it ends up looking like this, as expected:

```
2017-02-01 06:29:15 +0000 docker.6faad650faa6: {"log":"{\"timeMillis\":1485917543709,\"thread\":\"main\",\"level\":\"INFO\",\"loggerName\":\"com.imageintelligence.ava.api.Boot\",\"message\":\"{\\\"dom\\\":\\\"DOM\\\"}\",\"loggerFqcn\":\"org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger\",\"threadId\":1,\"threadPriority\":5}\r","com.amazonaws.ecs.cluster":"dombou","container_id":"6faad650faa6012af4f32df79901b42488543a5e6e53517fe3579b01ab2b6862","container_name":"/upbeat_booth","source":"stdout"}`
```

I use a filter like so, to parse the JSON:

```
<filter docker.**>
  @type parser
  format json
  key_name log
  reserve_data true
  hash_value_field log
</filter>
```

and I end up with semi-sanitized JSON:

```
2017-02-01 06:32:10 +0000 docker.68c794f7f694: {"source":"stdout","log":{"timeMillis":1485917543709,"thread":"main","level":"INFO","loggerName":"com.imageintelligence.ava.api.Boot","message":"{\"dom\":\"DOM\"}","loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger","threadId":1,"threadPriority":5},"com.amazonaws.ecs.cluster":"dombou","container_id":"68c794f7f6948d4261b9497947834651abbf766e9aa51a76f39d6895b7a9ac18","container_name":"/sad_hamilton"}
```

The issue is, the `message` field is still a string escaped JSON field. Any advice on how I can parse that inner JSON field as well? How do I stack filters?

Answer (score 17):

You could try sequential filters:

```
<filter docker.**>
  @type parser
  key_name log
  format json
  reserve_data true
</filter>

<filter docker.*.embeded_json.**>
  @type parser
  key_name message
  format json
  reserve_data true
</filter>
```

Comment: You are my savior !

Comment: @rhunwicks, it didn't work me. Does the sequential filters still work?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following plugin and let me know how it goes:

https://github.com/edsiper/fluent-plugin-docker

Comment: My understanding is that this works for the 'log' field, but nothing INSIDE the log field. I need something that will recursively deal with the innards of log. I shall give it a try though

Comment: Confirmed: It does not parse the inner json as I want

Comment: Didn't work for me either. So even in 2020 we don't have a way to parse inner json?

Answer (score 0):

Define a filter and use json_in_json pluggin for fluentd. After this filter define matcher for this filter to do further process on your log.

Thats helps you to parse nested json. U might also need to add
gem install fluent-plugin-json-in-json, if it is not already present.
refer - https://github.com/gmr/fluent-plugin-json-in-json